# Failed to load resource in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

I am making webpage in Laravel and I am stuck at really easy thing. I am trying to load external JS that resides in public folder. File permission for public folder is 777 so thats okay.

I am loading using

```
{!! Html::script('js/jquery.js') !!}
```

in head of blade template. This line of code makes:

```
<script src="http://devbud/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Which is also okay. But it still doesn't work. My jquery.js is in public/js folder, which is also okay.

So it should work, but it doesn't. Maybe it is a problem in my .htaccess file, it looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Is problem in .htaccess or should I look elswhere?

Comment: Are you sure you want the link to the script to be "http://devbud/js/jquery.js"?  Do you not want a proper domain, like devbud.com?

Comment: It is a virtual local host (http://devbud), when it goes online it will have .com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `config/app.php`, set your `url` to include the `public` directory:

```php
'url' => 'http://devbud/public',
```

However, this assumes that your app is running from that directory (that is to day that `index.php` resides there). A recommendation would be to make that directory your `DocumentRoot` - Laravel was designed for the other files and directories to be placed *above* the `DocumentRoot`.

Also, if you prefer to run from the sub-directory, you need to add a `RewriteBase` to your `.htaccess` file, just below `RewriteEngine On`:

```bash
RewriteBase /public/
```

Comment: http://devbud points to wamp/www/devbud/public - index.php resides here (I am using wamp). I tried what you have suggested, no luck.

Comment: I don't think you need to use that `Html` facade for this. Just manually enter `<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>`.